# Trouble with II7 + Win 2008 r2 + MVC4 + custom error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, custom-error-handling

I have te following problem, try to reproduce this:

1) 
If you are on a MVC site (**IIS7 / NOT CASSINI**), "example.com" try to navigate the current address: "example.com/a/b"

**Result: (expected) you´ll be redirected to your custom 404 page.**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg3pL.jpg]

2) now try this bug, again on IIS7, navigate exactly this address: "example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h"

**Result: (ERROR) cause of mvc only maps the first 2 folders, it trows a 404 error page of IIS, unintercepted by your mvc.**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2PRK.jpg]

3) Now let´s try this but in development with visual studio 2010 or greather, with cassini or IIS7 express, navigate "localhost:1234/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h"

Result: it will work exactly as espected, redirecting to the correct 404 page.

Why if everything haves the same sources, works different on production and development, is this a IIS7 bug or there´s any way to solve it?